# Exception while calling another screen in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I am new in IOS developing. In `Main.storyoard`, I added a new `viewcontroller`, assigned it to a new class("LoginViewController") and provided a storyboard-ID("loginview"). 
Then I added a button on the default `viewcontroller` and tried the following code to call the newly created `viewcontroller`.

```
    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main.storyboard";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginview"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

During debugging when I clicked the button to display the other screen I got the following exception

> 2016-05-04 12:04:40.793 gcmexample[1418:30458] *** Terminating app due
>   to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not
>   find a storyboard named 'Main.storyboard' in bundle NSBundle
>   
>   (loaded)'
>   *** First throw call stack: (     0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101150e65 **exceptionPreprocess + 165  1   libobjc.A.dylib
>
>   0x0000000100840deb objc_exception_throw + 48  2   UIKit
>
>   0x0000000101c21669 -[UIStoryboard name] + 0   3   gcmexample
>
>   0x000000010033f2d6 -[ViewController btnSignout:] + 86     4   UIKit
>
>   0x00000001014ff194 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
>     5   UIKit                               0x000000010166e6fc
>   -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67     6   UIKit                               0x000000010166e9c8 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
>     7   UIKit                               0x000000010166daf8
>   -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601    8   UIKit                               0x000000010156e49b -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835  9   UIKit 
>   0x000000010156f1d0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865   10  UIKit
>
>   0x000000010151db66 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263  11  UIKit
>
>   0x00000001014f7d97 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6844  12 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010107ca31
>   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   13  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010107295c
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556   14  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000101071e13 __CFRunLoopRun + 867     15  CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000101071828 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488     16  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000010492bad2 GSEventRunModal + 161  17  UIKit
>   0x00000001014fd610 UIApplicationMain + 171    18  gcmexample
>   0x000000010033ffdf main + 111     19  libdyld.dylib
>   0x000000010388c92d start + 1  20  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Does anyone know whats the error here? Please help.

Comment: NSString * storyboardName = @"Main"; // without extension ".storyboard"

Comment: try this :    NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This:-

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginview"];
    [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle: nil];
UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginview"];
[self.navigationController presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

Use this code it will help you to nevigate:

```
NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:YoustoryboardName bundle: nil];
    UIViewController * vcontroll = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginview"];
    [self presentViewController:vcontroll animated:YES completion:nil];
```